# jQuery mobile carousel - linking jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I have been looking for the jquery mobile Image slide show and found this link interesting https://github.com/blackdynamo/jQuery-Mobile-Carousel I have downloaded all the js files and inserted it. But it still doesn`t working.. Please find the code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Home</title>
<!-- Meta viewport tag is to adjust to all Mobile screen Resolutions-->
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Css/Jstyle.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Css/pag.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/jquery1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/jquery2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Css/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Css/jquery.mobile.carousel.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Css/jquery.ui.ipad.js" ></script>



<script type="text/javascript" src="css/pag.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

(function($) {
    $("#carousel1").carousel();
})(jQuery);

</script>



</head>
<body>


<div data-role="page">
Horizontal
<div style="height: 300px; width: 500px">
    <ul data-role="listview" id="carousel1" style="display: none;">
        <li><div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color:blue;">Page 1</div></li>
        <li><div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color:#837;">Page 2</div></li>
        <li><div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color:#999;">Page 3</div></li>

    </ul>
</div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

below link is github.

https://github.com/blackdynamo/jQuery-Mobile-Carousel

actually **jquery.mobile.carousel.js** is library file for slideshow effect.

but this library use jQuery UI's draggable function & simulate touch to mouse event also.

so, if you want use this lib. you should include all of js files in your html.

**Add**

following part is error

```
   <body onload=(function($) {
       $("#carousel1").carousel();

   })(jQuery);>
```

Fix as below

```
(function($) {
    $("#carousel1").carousel();
})(jQuery);
```

and javascript should be defined in <script> tag.

WRONG CASE :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Css/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.min.js" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Css/jquery.mobile.carousel.js" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Css/jquery.ui.ipad.js" />
```

RIGHT CASE :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Css/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.min.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="Css/jquery.mobile.carousel.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="Css/jquery.ui.ipad.js" />
```

Comment: I have done linking the above 3 js files.. But it`s still not working.. And also the css and js files of jquery mobile.. But it`s still not working.. Any idea why??

Comment: did you call carousel() function to element for using carousel? if not, check js code of your jsfiddle link like '$("#carousel1").carousel()'. unfortunately this library doesn't respect "jQuery Mobile Widget Factory spec.". so it doesn't support auto enhancing of document.

Comment: your code make a exception because of wrong syntax in script tag. let's try a code that i added to my answer. :)

Comment: OMG!! It`s still not working.. I have tried and edited the question again.. :(

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I have done everything as u mentioned. It`s still doesn`t seem to be working :( It will be very helpful for me if u reply.. I have updated the code. pls check..

Comment: Sorry, I read your comment very lately. It's not easy to find what is cause. if you're possible to show full code or test site, it's more helpful to solve your problem. :)